# LINQ to SQL: Invalid column name 'DepartureGate', even though the column exists

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I absolutely do not get this. The column exists in the table, I've ensured that the application is executing the query against the proper table in the proper database, and it still reports that it's an invalid column name.

I'm running NET 4.0, SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. Does anyone have any similar experience?

Executing queries against any other column name in the same table in the same database works extremely excellently. I added this column today and for some reason my application refuses to acknowledge the existence of this column.

Relevant column definition:
[image]

Relevant code:

```
(from x in flightDataContext.FlightDatas
where x.FlightDataId == FlightDataID && x.Departure == true
select new
{
  x.ArrivalStationCode,
  x.ArrivalStationName,
  x.DepartureTime,
  x.DepartureGate
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Some code? What's the error?

Comment: Please, paste some code and your table schema...

Comment: The error is as printed in the title.

Comment: Updated with the column definition as seen in SSMS2008.

Comment: @Maritim ,Show us your LINQ query

Comment: Are you grouping the table before trying to select it? Lets see the linq you're using

Comment: @Maritim column definition will not be of any help. Update your question with some cs code

Comment: Updated with relevant code.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid. I was getting this error when trying editing a service that inserts into a DB. I have 2 DB's that (should) have the same schema. I updated one schema and used that to update my DBML file, but I forgot to update the schema of the one I was actually trying to insert into. I spent 1.5 hours updating DBML files and debugging only to realize that I should have checked that the target DB is up to date in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.You can try the following solutions.

You should update your classes after the database changed(drag and drop your tables to the linq to sql file), so that the column is accessible with object name. if still problem exists then
the value you are saving in the coloumn is greater then the size specified for the coloumn. try varchar(MAX) if your coloumn is of varchar type.

Comment: I have no idea what was wrong, but some erroneous definition somewhere or some misspelt parameter somewhere probably. This didn't solve it, but it sure is eliminated. Accepted answer and thanks since you nudged me to try this.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this error, I discovered that I had some spurious `[Key]` attributes on one of my Model objects that wasn't actually part of the unique key definition for that object's table. They had been innocuously sitting there until I refactored another of the object's relationships. Once I removed them, the error about the columns being invalid vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Before this , delete the table and drag drog the table again on the DBML file and save the DBML.

```
var flight=    flightDataContext.FlightDatas.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.FlightDataId == FlightDataID && x.Departure);
```

Now you can access:

```
  flight.ArrivalStationCode,
  flight.ArrivalStationName,
  flight.DepartureTime,
  flight.DepartureGate
```